# What is the definition of "iat" in Commissariat/Secretariat

Tags: etymology, terminology

What is the definition of "iat" in Commissariat/Secretariat, also what are some other "iat" words. (Links, if you have any, please.)

Comment: So essentially all "iat" words are derived from french, which are derived from latin? (E.G Professoriat, Salariat, Lariat)

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Are you by any chance... a modern Major-General?  (And will we next see you on Weaponry.SE asking about Mauser rifles and javelins?)

Comment: @Nate Eldredge who are you talking to?

Comment: Sorry, it was a silly joke.  In Gilbert and Sullivan's comic opera [*The Pirates of Penzance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_of_penzance), there is a [song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major-General%27s_Song) where a "Modern Major-General" sings about how he would like to "know precisely what is meant by 'commisariat'".  In another line, he wishes he could "tell at sight a Mauser rifle from a javelin".

Answer (score 3):

The *-i-* just happens to be there because it is part of the words they were derived from, i.e. *secretarius* and *commissarius*. The ending *-at(e)* describes either 1) an office, function, or abstract entity related to the word it is derived from, or 2) a passive participial noun, such as *mandate* "something that is demanded". The ending *-at* is simply a spelling variation of *-ate*.

---

In Latin, the regular **past participle** of verbs is made by adding the suffix *-t-* to the stem plus the ending *-us/-a/-um* (1st/2nd declension). So English *minute* is from *minu-t-us* "diminished", from *minuo* "to diminish, to make small": a very small piece cut off from an hour. (Note that *diminish* is from the related Latin *di-minuo*.)

Words denoting an **abstract entity**, such as an action or an office, can be made by adding *-us* (4th declension) to the stem on *-t-*. So English *advent* is derived from *adven-t-us*, "the act or process of arriving", from *advenio* "to arrive".

When you want to form a past participle based on something that isn't a verb, you often add *-a-* in between. Based on that, *magister* "master" led to *magistr-a-t-us* (2nd declension) "someone made into a master, a magistrate", or (4th declension) "the office of being a master, the magistrature". Both words could legitimate be formed based on *magister*. This was also done with *secretari-us* (regular adjective) => *secretari-atus* (4th declension, abstract entity)¹ and *commissari-us*.

In French, both endings evolved into the ending *-(a)t*, from which English took *secretariat, commissariat, proletariat*, but also most of our other words on *-ate* and *-it(e)*, which were **mostly spelled without the *-e* until ca. 1400** in English, so says the *Oxford English Dictionary*. By that time, *-e* began to be regularly added to both kinds of words to mark the long vowel, but a few words kept their original French *-at* in English.

Verbs on *-(a)te* are also derived from the past-participial stem.

---

1) [Purified Google search for a form of the 4th declension of *secretariatus*:](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&hl=en&sout=1&biw=1080&bih=1754&tbs=li%3A1&q=secretariatu|secretariatui+est+-la+-el+-del+-il+-din) plenty of hits. [Purified Google search for a form of the 2th declension of *secretariatus*](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&hl=en&sout=1&biw=1080&bih=1754&tbs=li:1&q=secretariato%7Csecretariati%20est%20-la%20-el%20-del%20-il%20-din): only one hit, and that written in the 20th century. So *Secretariat* most probably comes from an abstract noun of the 4th declension.

Comment: Beat me to the punchline! (Though I don’t like the way you separate the t from the vowel in the participial suffix … I suppose it can’t really be helped in Latin, but still, it hurts a bit.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Hi! Why don't you like it? I did that to separate the participial/supine suffix *-t-* from the masculine suffix/ending *-us* (2nd declension, i.e. theme vowel o/u, endings us/i/o/um/o; i/orum/is/os/is): the latter is less relevant and no part of the class of *-t-us* abstract nouns, which have a different suffix/ending *-us* (4th declension, i.e. theme vowel *-u-* plus endings of the 3rd declension: -/(i)s/i/m/e; es/um/bus/es/bus). Or did you just mean some...visually aesthetic dislike of all those hyphens...

Comment: I only dislike it because it is in origin a stressed, non-ablauting vowel—the participial suffix is _*-tó-_ (_*-tós/-tóm/-tósi̯o/-tó-ei̯_, etc.), while the abstracts have a different (ablauting) suffix, _*-tu-/-teu̯_. This distinction has been quite lost in Latin, of course, by the initial stress and subsequent vowel changes and gender levellings, so the two appear to be simply _-t-_ + regular paradigmatic endings.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Ah okay, so you are saying this *-tó- cannot be analysed any further? Is it not the same theme vowel as found in, say, *bonus*? And can this *-t(e)u* not be further analysed either? Is there no relation at all between them? I am thinking of Greek *-t-* but I don't know. (BTW I wasn't analysing the suffix(es) that far back, I was just looking at the way they functioned in the classical period to make new words. One conventionally says participles and abstracts are formed based on the supine stem, in an almost synchronic terminology, disregarding the PIE/PL origins...)

Comment: Perhaps it is simply because the participial (or adjectival) suffix is always written as _*-tó-_ that the separation jars. Even Szemerényi states that the suffix is likely to be just a thematic variant of the whole set of _*-t-_ suffix forms, though of course it has the decidedly unthematic quality of being invariably stressed and invariably invariable (no o/e alternation). I suppose there can be no doubt that the t present in both _*-tó-_, _*-ti/tei̯-_, and _*-tu/teu̯-_ is the same, and that the following vowels are extensions to it; but separating them is just not normally done. [cont’d]

Comment: [cont’d] At least not within the proto-language itself. It makes more sense for Latin, though you might well ask why not separate the nominative _-s_ then. At some point, separating etymologically distinct elements becomes almost pointless; for example, if you separate _magistrātus_ as _mag-i-s-t-r-[ā]-t-u-s_, you don’t have much point left in the separation anymore.

Comment: Okay, that analysis of the PIE suffix sounds good to me. I'm not sure about conventions regarding hyphenation in PIE notation (it seems to fluctuate), but I will gladly accept that *-tó- is generally written as one. What do you think of this hypothesis: classicists/linguists do not hyphenate inside a morpheme, but they can hyphenate between any (semi-)morphemes; however, they only do so when it seems useful. If you apply that to my answer, my thinking was that the hyphen in *t-us* was relevant because *-t-* is common to both but *-us* is two different (semi-)morphemes.

Comment: Another question: I wonder how **-tó-* resulted in e.g. *actam*. Do etymologists explain this as a kind of contraction in PIE or PL of the theme vowel **-ó-* with a feminine suffix or theme vowel *-(y)a-*, so **-tó-(y)a-* => *-ta-*? Or do they reason that forms like *actam* were only created after PIE, and that (Proto-)Latin had somehow shortened the suffix **-tó-* to **-t-* at some stage before *actam*? Or does it make more sense to suppose that the **-ó-* was seen as something that could be detached from **-t-* if needed already in PIE or whenever the feminine suffix or theme vowel appeared?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the feminines are an innovation in Latin, a quite logical analogy. I don't _think_ Greek has any feminines with this suffix, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Not sure I understand entirely, but do you mean words like *praktos*, "that can be done, that is done"? They work like regular adjectives of the 1st/2nd declension, they can take the feminine suffix *-(y)a-*: http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=lsj&lang=el&word=prakto%2fs&filter=CUTF8 I was taught this *-t-* was cognate to the Latin *-t-*.

Comment: You're right—there are full paradigms in Greek, too. Which would imply an o/e alternation not otherwise found with this suffix. Must investigate a bit further—for some reason, I never really thought much about this before.

Answer (score 2):

It’s basically a mixture of various endings.

In Latin, there are a group of adjectives that are derived with the suffix *-ārius*; some of these include:

> *sēcrētārius* (‘having to do with a *sēcrētum* [secret]’)
>   *commissārius* (‘having to do with being *commissus* [in charge/committed]’)
>   *prōlētārius* (‘having to do with *prōlēs* [offspring, progeny]’

So the *-ārius* suffix means something like ‘having to do with *X*’.

These words were all originally adjectives, but for some reason, words with this particular suffix were particularly prone to be used as nouns. *Sēcretārius*, for example, meant something like ‘secretive’ or ‘confidential’, but went on to become used almost exclusively as a noun denoting a person who was these things: a secretary (or confidant).

Once this was the situation, there naturally arose a need to create an adjective corresponding to these nouns. The choice for a suffix to do this seems to have (somewhat oddly, perhaps) fallen on an analogical use of the suffix *-ātus*, which is really the passive participle suffix for first-declension verbs (*āmō* ‘I love’ -> *āmātus* ‘[be]loved’).

Why the late Romans chose this particular suffix is quite obscure—its meaning of ‘having been *X*-ed’ does not *really* fit with an adjective that just means ‘having to do with *X*’, after all … but choose it they did:

> *sēcrētārius* -> *sēcrētāriātus* ‘having to do with someone who has to do with secrets’
>   *commissārius* -> *commissāriātus* ‘having to do with someone who has to do with having been put in charge’ (!)
>   *prōlētārius* -> *prōlētāriātus* ‘having to do with someone who has to do with offspring’

These might seem like quite roundabout ways to say things, but this kind of ‘recursive derivation’ is quite common in Latin. I don’t think the Romans really thought about them in that way; they probably just thought of *sēcrētārius* as a simplex word from which an adjective was derived.

As happened to their ‘parent’ words, the adjectives in *-(āri)ātus* in their turn also started to be used as nouns. Since the nominalised forms of *-ārius* adjectives often denoted people, the nominalised forms of the *-(āri)ātus* adjectives naturally tended to describe either places or groups that were connected to these people.

Since then, the words passed into French and lost their final syllables (and some vowel fronting and other historical magic took place to turn *-ārius* into *-aire* in Modern French and *-ary* in Modern English), and voilà: you have words with *-ary* and derived words in *-ariat* in English.

Comment: By the way, you seem to be saying here that the likes of *secretariatus* are derived from the past participles, not the nouns of the 4th declension?

Comment: Not really derived _from_ the past participles as such. They represent quite a late derivation, so I would imagine the past participle suffix was just used as a kind of generic adjectivising suffix, semi-separately from its true participial meaning. Adjectival uses seem to predate nominal uses, so I would think the fourth-declension abstracts an unlikely candidate for this particular derivation.

Comment: Okay, sure, the adjectival/"supine" stem on *-t-* without the *-u-* of the 4th declension, then. But I think the English *was* derived from the noun of the 4th declension in the case of *secretariat*. We know there was a word *secretariatus* meaning "the office of being a secretary". As you say about the form of the 2nd declension, *its meaning of ‘having been X-ed’ does not really fit with an adjective that just means ‘having to do with X’*. Shouldn't that be strong an argument for a derivation from the 4th declension?

Comment: ...There are no participial nouns on *-tus* (2nd) with the required meaning that I know of in Latin (only neuter *-tum* could even come close, though it would still be passive), but very many on *-tus* (4th) with the required meaning. And we have plenty of English words on *-(a)t(e)* that are proven to have come from the 4th declension, such as *senate, triumvirate, state, syndicatus, etc.

Comment: Fourth-declension abstracts would be a more fitting basis, yes; though I don't see where the _-ā-_ comes from, then. Applying a verbal stem vowel to an entirely nominal derivation seems quite arbitrary and odd, even for late Latin.

Answer (score 1):

These two words come from French - and I believe they are the only ones ending by *-iat*, which has no specific meaning.

"Secrétariat" comes itself from Latin secretarius, connected with "secret" ; there is tendency in Roman languages, especially Catalan, to end words by -iat ; "secrétairerie" has existed in French, but could not survive for euphonic reasons (logically derived, but a true gargle).

Perhaps "commissariat", the origin of which is also Latin (commissus), but the derivation more obscure, has been forged by imitation ?